# Python for loop returns only the first value

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to retrieve values from a JSON but my for loop is getting only the first values several times:

I'm using the following for loop:

```
def get_nodeid1():
    url='https://%s/api/node/class/fabricNode.json' % apic
    response = requests.get(url, cookies=session_cookie, timeout=2, verify=False)
    json_data = json.loads(response.text)
    node_id = json_data['imdata'][0]['fabricNode']['attributes']['name']
    for node in node_id:
        m1 = json_data['imdata'][0]['fabricNode']['attributes']['name']  
        m2 = json_data['imdata'][0]['fabricNode']['attributes']['serial']
        m3 = json_data['imdata'][0]['fabricNode']['attributes']['address']
        print(f"Node ID: {m1} Serial: {m2} Address: {m3}")
```

The result is 7 times the first entry:

```
Node ID: LEAF101 Serial: FDO21230U65 Address: 10.1.152.66
Node ID: LEAF101 Serial: FDO21230U65 Address: 10.1.152.66
Node ID: LEAF101 Serial: FDO21230U65 Address: 10.1.152.66
Node ID: LEAF101 Serial: FDO21230U65 Address: 10.1.152.66
Node ID: LEAF101 Serial: FDO21230U65 Address: 10.1.152.66
Node ID: LEAF101 Serial: FDO21230U65 Address: 10.1.152.66
Node ID: LEAF101 Serial: FDO21230U65 Address: 10.1.152.66
```

Comment: What does the json file look like?

Comment: You are not using `node in node_id` inside the loop. You are accessing `json_data['imdata'][0]` every time.

Comment: Where are you confused?  You *specifically* access only the first value: `json_data['imdata'][0]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that you want to loop over `json_data['imdata']`. Your original code never refers to the node in the loop. Try this:

```
def get_nodeid1():
    url='https://%s/api/node/class/fabricNode.json' % apic
    response = requests.get(url, cookies=session_cookie, timeout=2, verify=False)
    json_data = json.loads(response.text)
    for node in json_data['imdata']:
        m1 = node['fabricNode']['attributes']['name']  
        m2 = node['fabricNode']['attributes']['serial']
        m3 = node['fabricNode']['attributes']['address']
        print(f"Node ID: {m1} Serial: {m2} Address: {m3}")
```

Comment: thats it! sorry for the rookie question :)

Answer (score 0):

You are actually iterating over the 7 characters of the string "LEAF101". Also, you are not using the ’node’ variable anywhere within the looped block.

You probably want to iterate over a dict on a higher level in the json_data and then use the node variable as key when accessing subordinate variables.